# I am not able to map the result of this SQLite query. Is it possible to do this in java?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, mobile, android-room

```
DAO: 
@Query ("SELECT COUNT (created_at) 'number_of_occurrence', datetime (created_at, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') 'local_datetime' FROM 'transaction' GROUP BY datetime (created_at, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') ORDER BY created_at DESC ")
 List <List <WrapperTransactionModel>> groupByCreatedAt ();
```

result image

[image]

```
Repository:
public List<List<WrapperTransactionModel>>   groupByCreatedAt() {
    return this.mDataBase.groupByCreatedAt();
}
```

Error received:
error: Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor

Class created in an attempt to solve the problem

```
public class WrapperTransactionModel {

@ColumnInfo(name = "number_of_occurrence")
private List<String> numberOfOccurrence;

@ColumnInfo(name = "local_datetime")
private List<String> localDatetime;
```

hidden access methods(get's and set's)

All help is very welcome!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Room has limited types/objects that can be stored and retrieved. It cannot store/ or retrieve a List(directly) and hence why Room is saying that it doesn't know how to handle the extracted data.

Room can store Strings, it can also retrieve Strings into a List of Strings.

As such I believe that you may want WrapperTransactionModel to be

```
class WrapperTransactionModel {
    @ColumnInfo(name = "number_of_occurrence")
    private String numberOfOccurrence;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "local_datetime")
    private String localDatetime;
    ....
```

along with :-

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT (created_at) 'number_of_occurrence', datetime (created_at, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') 'local_datetime' FROM 'transaction' GROUP BY datetime (created_at, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') ORDER BY created_at DESC ")
List<WrapperTransactionModel> groupByCreatedAt ();
```

Perhaps consider this demonstration of the above that resembles your using your data:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TransactionDatabase db;
    AllDao dao;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = Room.databaseBuilder(this,TransactionDatabase.class,"transction.db")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
        dao = db.getDao();

        /*
            Add 15 rows of testing data where
                the first row will have a created_at datetime based upon 60 days ago
                the next 3 rows 30 days ago
                and the remaining 11 today
         */
        long second = 1000;
        long near_a_month = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
        long adjust = near_a_month * 2;
        for(int i=0; i < 15; i++) {
            if (i > 0 && i < 3) adjust = near_a_month;
            if (i > 3) adjust = 0;
            dao.insertTransaction(new Transaction(String.valueOf((System.currentTimeMillis() / second) - adjust)));
        }

        // Get the data using the Query
        List<WrapperTransactionModel> myTransactionModels = dao.groupByCreatedAt();

        // Write the extracted data out to the log (3 row counts 11,3 and 1 )
        for(WrapperTransactionModel wtm: myTransactionModels) {
            Log.d("WTMINFO","NumberOfOccurrences = " + wtm.getNumberOfOccurrence()+ " LocalDateTime = " +wtm.getLocalDatetime());
        }
    }
}
```

- Note runs on main thread for brevity and convenience.

The result written to the log :-

```
2021-04-22 19:57:06.738 D/WTMINFO: NumberOfOccurrences = 11 LocalDateTime = 2021-04-22 19:57:06
2021-04-22 19:57:06.739 D/WTMINFO: NumberOfOccurrences = 3 LocalDateTime = 2021-03-23 20:57:06
2021-04-22 19:57:06.739 D/WTMINFO: NumberOfOccurrences = 1 LocalDateTime = 2021-02-21 20:57:06
```

Comment: Good morning @Mike T!
I ended up taking another approach that worked perfectly for me.
Still, thank you very much for your help!
Now I'm going to sleep kkkkkkkkkkkk.